# OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset/training_set/cats/._cat.643.jpg'

Tags: python, macos, keras

Do you all have any insights on why I could be getting this operating system error when trying to run a convolution neural network (CNN) with Keras?

Also, when I run the code again, the same error is thrown but it is with a different image.

Thank you!

Here is the code, error message, and important screen shots:

```
# Convolutional Neural Network

# Installing Theano
# pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git

# Installing Tensorflow
# Install Tensorflow from the website: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html

# Installing Keras
# pip install --upgrade keras

# Part 1 - Building the CNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense

# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 8000,
                         nb_epoch = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 2000)
```

Here is the error message:

```
  File "/Users/anthonypendleton/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2822, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))

  OSError: cannot identify image file 'dataset/training_set/dogs/._dog.3513.jpg'
```

[image: Run 1]

[image: Run 2]

[image: Directory view from Finder]

[image: The image(s) open fine in Preview]

Comment: put code and error message as text. My Python can't run code from screenshot. My mouse can't copy/paste text from screenshot.

Comment: You right. Thank you for the reminder. I edited the post.

Comment: Does that file in the message exist? Can you open it in a regular image editor?

Comment: Yep! Opens fine in Preview. Please see the newly attached screenshot. All of the images open fine. I even tried to recopy and paste the new folders to try and see if there is an issue with the permissions or something.

Answer (score 1):

you fail in macos temporary file error.  `._dog.3513.jpg` and `dog.3513.jpg` are different files. You need to clean your data folder.

Here is function to clean folder form hidden files with given extension:
You can use it before `flow_from_directory`. Be patient with it, to not remove needed data.

```
from glob import glob
import os

def clean_directory(dir_path, ext=".jpg"):
    files = glob(os.path.join(dir_path, ".*" + ext))  # this line find all files witch starts with . and ends with given extension
    for file_path in files:
        os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Do you mind referring me to a resource so I can try that?

Comment: I deleted everything in ~/library/caches and tried to run the code but the same error is thrown.

Comment: Because macos recreate it. I add function which should clean folder from problematic files. Be careful with it and befor the test make a copy of data.